# Mess while changing a Special item color

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to change the color of a Special item in a recyclerview

I used the following code for this request but when there are too many items, I scroll down

Background color of all other items also change

This case is in the normal recyclerview

What should I do to solve this problem?

My adapter code

```
public class LastCommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LastCommentAdapter.LastCommentViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Comment> comments;
View view;

public LastCommentAdapter(Context context, List<Comment> comments) {
    this.context = context;
    this.comments = comments;
}

@Override
public LastCommentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_last_comment_item, parent, false);
    return new LastCommentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final LastCommentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Comment comment = comments.get(position);
    holder.commentUser.setText(comment.getName_user());
    holder.commentContent.setText(comment.getContent());
    holder.numberSubComment.setText(String.valueOf(comment.getNumber_sub_comment()));
    if (comment.getId()==7) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return comments.size();
}

public class LastCommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView commentContent;
    private TextView commentUser;
    private TextView numberSubComment;

    public LastCommentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        commentContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_comment_item_content);
        commentUser = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_comment_item_user);
        numberSubComment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_comment_item_answer);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did correct but you also need to add the code for else statement because of the Id change. The issue is the special item is going to change and it's not getting the white background again because of else statement.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final LastCommentViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Comment comment = comments.get(position);
holder.commentUser.setText(comment.getName_user());
holder.commentContent.setText(comment.getContent());
holder.numberSubComment.setText(String.valueOf(comment.getNumber_sub_comment()));
if (comment.getId()==(Special Item Id)) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}else{
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YOUR_COLOR);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your should change your code like below

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final LastCommentViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Comment comment = comments.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YourDefaultColorOFItem);
        if(comment != null){
           holder.commentUser.setText(comment.getName_user());
           holder.commentContent.setText(comment.getContent());
        holder.numberSubComment.setText(String.valueOf(comment.getNumber_sub_comment()));
          if (comment.getId()==7) {
             holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
          } else holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YourDefaultColorOFItem);
       }
    }
```